# Elements are not getting populated in the drop down in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I created an array of elements in component.ts and tried populating in HTML but I am not able to do so.

#### Component.ts

```js
categories: [
    {
        id:1,
        name:"Action"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:"Comedy"
    },
    {
        id:3,
        name:"Thriller"
    },
    {
        id:4,
        name:"Crime"
    },
    {
        id:5,
        name:"Sci-Fi"
    }
];
```

#### HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [value]="cat.id">
            {{cat.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add = instead of : for category. Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2j1etc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts